# How can I make speechUtterance API utter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, avspeechutterance

When I type in something in the text area element and then click on the read button nothing is being uttered. The console doesn't throw any error and I can't identify where I've gone wrong either. I went on the "SpeechUtterance" MDN documentation and as far as I can tell I've followed all the right steps. Help please!

```js
const read = document.getElementById("read");
const pause = document.getElementById("pause");
const stop = document.getElementById("stop");
const speed = document.getElementById("speed");
const text = document.getElementById("text");


read.addEventListener("click", () => {
  readText(text.value)
});

pause.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pauseText();
});


function readText(dummy) {
  var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(dummy);
  if(speechSynthesis.speaking && speechSynthesis.paused) {
    return speechSynthesis.resume()
  }

  if(speechSynthesis.speaking) return;

  console.log(utterThis)
  console.log(speechSynthesis)


  utterThis.text = dummy;
  utterThis.rate = speed.value
  text.disabled = true;
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterThis)
  utterThis.addEventListener("end", () => {
    text.disabled = false
  })
}

function pauseText() {
  if(speechSynthesis.speaking)  speechSynthesis.pause();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: purple;
}


textarea {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

textarea:focus {
  background: green;

}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="text" name="name" rows="30" cols="100"></textarea>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="speed">Speed</label>
      <input id="speed" type="number" min="0" step="1" max="10">
      <button id="read" type="button" name="button">Read</button>
      <button id="pause" type="button" name="button">Pause</button>
      <button id="stop" type="button" name="button">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me (Chrome on Windows, 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)). What browser are you testing this with? Are you sure it supports this API? Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (x86_64). According to MDN SpeechSynthesisUtterance is fully supported by Chrome

Comment: Can you share the inputs to the form itself that cause this behavior to not work? For instance, what content are you attempting to have `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` utter? What speed have you input?

Comment: I've just updated to Version 98.0.4758.80 (Official Build) (x86_64) and the API is now working.

Comment: Well it might not have anything to do with the browser. I typed in a text in the area element and then clicked on the read button. Everything worked fine. But when I clicked on it a second time nothing was being uttered. I even refreshed the page, re-clicked on the read button multiple times but in vain. I figure there must be something wrong with my if statement.